# Am I helping co-workers too much

Tags: teamwork

I am not a manager, but it is one of my goals to become one.

When my coworker has an issue with something such as people not stocking when and someone else does it. I say sorry I will try help and take some blame to be a team player.

One of my coworkers gets mad at me because the co-worker think that I am taking the lead like manager should do.

Am I team player or am I taking to much of leader position?

Comment: Hi Aaron and welcome to the workplace.SE. Your question seems to me primarly opinion based and, with the details give, it will be hard to give you any meaningful answer. Perhaps you can edit it, to make it clearer what goals you want to achieve? Also have a look in the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: A leader would seek to address the situation so it doesn't happen again and not just take the blame for someone else failing to do their work.

Comment: Is this impacting your work to any degree, and what does your manager say? I would speak to your manager and see if they are happy with you continuing with this approach. You never know, they may be happy with it and may actually be watching you and thinking you may have manager potential.

Comment: You should ask your supervisor.  She/he will be the one best equipped to answer this question.

Comment: Hi! :-) How long have you been at this company? Have you always had the same position? Have you asked your colleague, when they get mad at you, what's _wrong_ with you stepping up and behaving the way you do? Have you tried defending yourself to your colleague? If so, what did you say?

Answer (score 2):

**There is a difference between Blame and Responsibility.**

One of the things you need to be *very* careful about when thinking and talking about these issues is to not conflate those two concepts.

Blame is about finding someone to say is at fault, to associate a failure with.  Responsibility is about owning future outcomes and making sure failure doesn't happen - as well as the internalization that *you're* the person who determines whether failure will occur.

So here's how the two look:

> "Sorry the shelves weren't restocked this morning - I probably should've done it."

... that's Blame.  Your voluntarily taking it, but it's still just Blame.  It's giving people someone to associate the failure with.  You're not saying anything about whether it will happen again, what you're going to change, or anything.  You're just giving people someone to associate with that failure.

> "I can make it part of my end-of-shift checklist to restock if nobody else has done it by the time I'm about to leave?"

Aka, it doesn't matter who's *fault* this current failure is.  That's not where your focus is.  Instead, it's about taking ownership of it *getting done* in the future.  You're offering "This won't happen again, because I'll make sure it doesn't."

So along that front: if you're taking "Blame" for things - who cares?  Taking Blame doesn't help.  If that's what you're doing, I can imagine you would be annoying to coworkers.  But if you're taking Responsibility?  Awesome!

**And that's the core thing: Good leaders don't blame (or simply take blame) - they take responsibility.**  Is XYZ a problem?  I'll make sure it never happens again.  Things went bad because of ABC?  I'll figure out some way of making it go better in the future.

**Finally, don't conflate Managers with Leaders.**  Everyone can be a leader.  Everyone *should* be a leader.  Taking responsibility and owning outcomes is something that's valuable at every job level.

Comment: Everyone should be a leader? How does that work? It sounds like "Everyone should be above average" to me.

Comment: @TonyK - You might be thinking of Leader as in "tells people what to do."  I'd argue a better interpretation of Leader is "someone who acts responsibly and carries themselves in a way that people look up to and aspire to."  I'm a leader where I work - but it's not due to any authority.  The reasons people view me as a leader are things that anyone can (and should!) do - I work hard, I take ownership of the success/failure of anything I'm involved with and do whatever I can to make sure those things succeed - and I work hard at continuously improving.

Comment: It seems like we're not using the same dictionary, then...

Answer (score 1):

The more important question, I think, is how do your manager(s) feel about it? Do they appreciate you stepping up and taking some of the load off of them or do they think you’re overstepping your role and doing work outside of your purview. If your manager is happy, I wouldn’t worry about this co-worker. He probably wants a promotion as well and just doesn’t like you stealing his thunder. If you're not sure how your managers feel, you can always ask.